# General form for Eigenvector of a 3 by 3 symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am looking for a general form for both Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors for an arbitrary 3 by 3  symmetric matrix. Is there a compact form present in the literature? I have tried using Mathematica and it  seems pretty messy even after simplification.

Comment: If you are dealing with a real matrix, you can get a formula for the eigenvalues using the trigonometric solution of the cubic equation. It's quite gruesome, but perhaps not as gruesome as you might at first fear.

Comment: Unfortunately my matrix is not real-valued!

Comment: @AnginaSeng can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, which is a cubic whose coefficients are polynomials in the entries of the matrix.  There are formulas for the roots of a cubic, but they are messy.  It's not going to get less messy if you substitute in the expressions for the coefficients in terms of the matrix entries.  The eigenvectors form
a basis of the null space of $A - \lambda I$ where $A$ is your matrix and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue.  Still more messy.

Here's one help for the last step, though.  Assume there are three distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$.  An eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ is
$(A - \lambda_2 I)(A - \lambda_3 I) x$ where $x$ is any vector that is not an eigenvector for $\lambda_2$ or $\lambda_3$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was hoping if at all a pretty expression for eigenvector is available, but i presume my first guess that such an explicit expression being messy holds true :(